# Swift: Drifting of scene.pointOfView with ARkit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, drift

I'm playing with the ARKit and as it works generally well, (I've tried on iPad Pro (2017) and iPhoneX. I've discovered a device that generates serious drifting of the pointOfView of the scene: the iPad Pro 12.9" (2015).

At first, I thought the problem was with the sensors, because even the most basic ARKit sample project from Apple drifts eventually. 
Then I used the IKEA Place App, and it's stable!

I tried applying corrective measure to the scene.pointOfView.transform (averaging the transform of multiple frames, but I'm afraid that I end up fighting with the ARKit to set it first.

So, my question is:
Does anyone know how to modify the camera node's transform AFTER the ARKit does?

Comment: would like to know if you got answers.

Comment: In fact, no... in my case it was linked to one specific iPad that had was a little over-reactive on one gyro but still not enough to be deemed faulty by the Apple Store. 
I guess Ikea did their own layer of code on top of the anchoring  processes.